# How do I create an SAP icon with two character text in UI5?

Tags: icons, sapui5

I want to create an SAP icon like below by setting the icon property of a StandardListItem, how do I do it?

[image]

I want to be able to change the above two characters dynamically i.e, the icon is not a static resource but should be dynamically generated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280337/5846045

Answer (score 0):

`icon` property of [StandardListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardListItem.html) takes URI as input parameter.

```
var oListItem =  new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "Name",
    description:"Description",
    icon:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgcgp.png"
 });
```

[Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6kb5rcz/)

Comment: Hi Sunil, thank you for the answer, I forgot to mention an additional point in the question, sorry for that! Have edited it now.

Comment: you want something like icon of contacts in android..?

Comment: Exactly! but with two letters instead of one.